# IOS Swift Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat?' and 'Int' but '==' works

Tags: ios, swift

I understand the difference between CGFloat and Int but strangely I was able to use in an if loop

```
if image?.size.width == 200 {
  // CODE
}
```

where image is an unwrapped UIImage and the size.width is of CGFloat whereas the number 200 is of type Int and this can be run on Xcode with no compiler errors.

However with:

```
if image?.size.width <= 200 {
 // CODE
}
```

Xcode returns the error:

> Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat?'
>   and 'Int'

and Xcode can not run. I have looked through Apple docs on CGFloat and their '==' and '<=' operator specifications and they make sure that both sides have to be CGFloats and I dont have any extensions handling == operators between CGFloats and Int (Unless its in a cocoapod?)

My question is why does one work and the other is an error?

Comment: Any chance it's because one is `Int` - which is *not* an optional - and the other is `CGFloat?` - which is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misunderstood why the first case worked: 200 is a numeric literal, the compiler saw that you are checking this literal for equality against an `Optional<CGFloat>` so it interpreted 200 as a `CGFloat`. Since an `Optional<CGFloat>` is either nil or an actual number, you can test if it's equal to 200.

The second case is about ordering of the two values. The compiler does not have a rule about ranking `nil` against an actual value. You have to make that decision yourself.

In your case, I think this is what you actually want:

```
if let width = image?.size.width, width <= 200 {
 // CODE
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, is there any resources that could further explain literals? Apple docs is a bit wordy and it explains well but not really why they exist.

Answer (score 1):

It is just because you didn't unwrapped your float value ignorer to compare.

You cannot compare optional to non-optional for getting order.

See Even if you have both side CGFloat one as CGFLoat? and other non-optional CGFloat you can equat "==" them but you can't get get order by "<", ">", ">=", "<=" operators

[image]